# getting the hooks via scp in git

Tags: git, ssh

I am still new to git (one week as we have switched from SVN).
We are using egit with Eclipse but I also have git-bash and I am pretty experienced Linux user (in the past).

When I tried to push I got the following error:

```
ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 
anthony.chamberlain@XXX.XXX.com:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
And then amend the commit:
git commit --amend
```

I found the git directory (/f/.git) and did a cd /f/.git/hooks (because that is the directory it would scp to) and then I issued the scp command

```
scp -p -P 29418 
anthony.chamberlain@XXX.XXX.com:hooks/commit-msg  .
```

which is the same as what it told me to do as I am already in the correct directory (git-dir/hooks)

My SCP command timed out.  I remembered from my linux experience about the authorized_keys and the ID.  I went to our git page and sae whit:

[image]

I followed the directions and took my id-rsa.put contents and pasted it in the window below.

[image]

(for security reasons I am not listing the actual data here).  I also took what was displayed in the server host keys file and put it in my .ssh/authorized-keys and did a chmod 600 on it.

I tried the scp command again and it timed out.  I tried ssh to the port 29418 and it timed out.  I did a ping XXX.XXX.com and got

```
Pinging XXX.XXX.com [XX.XXX.XX.XXX] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from XX.XXX.XX.XXX: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=246
```

We do not have telnet so I could not try telnetting.  Doing an ssh with no port says 22 connection refused.

So I am not sure why it is not scping.  I have run out of ideas.  Any ideas?

By the way, I thought it best to XXX out the actual machine name and IP address for security but rest assured I used the correct ones.

And I do believe our git server is unix or linux.  My desktop is windows but I used git-bash.

Comment: Are you using `gerrit`? It looks that you can push, what `protocol` do you use? Show us the output of `git config -l | grep remote`.

Comment: nothing resulted from the grep:

Comment: $ git config -l | grep remote\n
/f/.ssh\n
$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: The problem with comments is you can't make new lines.  Anyway there are three lines but no remote output.  I think the problem is chmod does not work in git-bash because it is on windows?

Comment: The problem is that scp is timing out and I can't figure out why.

Comment: If there is no `remote` defined how does `git push` work for you? And what does `git remote` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162767/discussion-between-tony-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).